# Infusionsoft Form Submission API

Tags: forms, api, submission, infusionsoft

I have been using Infusionsoft form embedded in html page but now I want to send data to Infusionsoft form using their API. I checked their APIs but could not figure out which one should be used to submit data to the Infusionsoft form. Can someone please help me with this?

https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/

Thanks for looking into this.

Thank you, Naresh

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use REST API instead of XML RPC. Developer center already marked XML RPC to "legacy" module, and I guess they will replace "XML RPC" sooner or later.
2. Regarding to your question, you will need to define what data set you want to update. 
   For example, if your form is going to insert a new contact, you will need 2 things from your code.

   - First, prepare the parameters such like "email_addresses", "phone_numbers" and "given_name".
   - Second, POST request with parameters to this URL "https://api.infusionsoft.com/crm/rest/v1/contact?access_token=123abc" after authentication.

Ways to test:
Try REST API calls on page https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To pull Webformvia API you will have to use following method, this will pull the HTML form:

> [Retrieve a Form's HTML](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#webform-retrieve-a-form-s-html)

to submit a data to Infusionsoft via API
You will have to use Create contact and update contact API:

> [Create Contact](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-create-a-contact)
> [Update COntact](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-update-a-contact)

XML RPC is still in use but Infusionsoft suggests to use REST API methods

> [Create a Contact](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/createContactUsingPOST)
> [Update a Contact](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/updatePropertiesOnContactUsingPATCH_2)
> Single API call for two methods: [Create or Update a Contact](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/createOrUpdateContactUsingPUT)